# How to update my code to be able to re-size rectangles?

Tags: c#, winforms

This WinForm application allows the user to draw multiple rectangles in a PictureBox but once the rectangle is drawn there is no way to alter it.  I would like all of the rectangles to have the ability to be re-sized, and eventually implement an undo option but my main focus now is re-sizing.

I'm really confused on where to start altering my code to include re-sizing.  I'd like to do something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30434/A-Resizable-Graphical-Rectangle) with my rectangles.  Any advice/assistance would would be much appreciated!

My Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   Point startPos;
   Point currentPos;
   bool drawing;
   List<Rectangle> myRectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void selectFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           //Initiate new OpenFileDialog
           //Filter for img and bmp files
           //Start looking in root of c:
           OpenFileDialog myFile = new OpenFileDialog();
           myFile.Filter = "Image Files(*.img, *.bmp) |*.img; *.bmp;";
           myFile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";

           //Set background image of pictureBox to file selected through OpenFileDialog
           if (myFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(myFile.FileName);
           }
       }

       catch (Exception error)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error loading the selected file.  Original error: " + error.Message);             
       }
   }

   private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.Close();
   }

   private void clearAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   private void zoomToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   private void undoLastActionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   private void redoLastActionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   private Rectangle getRectangle()
   {
        return new Rectangle(
           Math.Min(startPos.X, currentPos.X),
           Math.Min(startPos.Y, currentPos.Y),
           Math.Abs(startPos.X - currentPos.X),
           Math.Abs(startPos.Y - currentPos.Y));
   }

   private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           currentPos = startPos = e.Location;
           drawing = true;
       }       
   }

   private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       currentPos = e.Location;
       if (drawing) pictureBox1.Invalidate();
   }

   private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       if (myRectangles.Count > 0) e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Black, myRectangles.ToArray());
       if (drawing) e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, getRectangle());
   }

   private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (drawing)
       {
           drawing = false;
           var rect = getRectangle();
           if (rect.Width > 0 && rect.Height > 0) myRectangles.Add(rect);
           pictureBox1.Invalidate();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't really alter rectangles. You need an object to save your state - size, color and position (and other properties) of your rectangles. Then you would simply redraw the entire scene every time something was updated. 
Once something is drawn on screen it's there. Even "normal" controls are redrawn-that portion of the screen is "invalidated" and redrawn according to the state saved in some object.
With regard to creating interactive rectangles, you'd have to catch mouse events and find over which rectangle were they made, then apply proper modifications to your state and redraw the scene.

Comment: @Mike Guthrie - The code I've been trying to incorporate into mine, the link I supplied, shows the a rectangle with 8 little squares for resizing on the corners and sides; that is ideally what I would like to make happen.  At the very least be able to grab one of the four corners to adjust the size.

Comment: @Stonehead - I've read a few things that mention what you are talking about, but my c# skills are not at the level that I fully understand how to make that happen.  It took me almost a week to get to where I now with my code.

Comment: And how does your user go about drawing a rectangle?

Comment: @DonBoitnott By holding left mouse click and dragging it out to the area desired then releasing the mouse button.

Comment: Way too broad a question, I'm afraid.  In short, draw all the little squares along with your rectangle.  Then track the identity of every rectangle so you can find it on MouseOver.  Then draw a resize grip when that happens.  Then handle MouseDown, then drag, then...  Get the picture?  There is no short and you have a lot left to do before you get anywhere near that example.

Comment: I kind of get what you're saying...  Like I said in an earlier comment, I struggled to get this far, and I'm well aware at how not simple this task will be.  I'll keep plugging away at trying and googling and hopefully someone is able to come up with a not in short answer that would help a novice like me.

Comment: The task is easy but it has a LOT of work. Many different cases. For example drawing the rectangle, it depends where the mouse is in respect to where initialy you start the rectangle. If it is in the right side(and down), the pivot point remains the same, otherwise it changes. I will give you code for one rectangle